# Run a batch file in Android

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, automation, scripts

I have WhatsApp installed, and the notifications from one group that I am admin for are driving me mad.

WhatsApp has the facility to "mute" notifications for 8 hours, but I have to do this manually every night. I would like to be able to just let a script do that every night at a set time.

Is that possible?

Comment: What about the "Do not disturb" mode of your devices?

Comment: This is an XY problem. You want to do X and think that Y ought to be the solution, and hence, you are asking  for Y instead of X. In addition to DND as Robert mentioned, you can install and configure a third-party app to snooze / dismiss all or selective notifications from Whatsapp during A to B hours. AFAIK, MacroDroid can be configured to "selectively"  or in entirety dismiss all notifications of an app during A-B hours.

Comment: Also, a script or anything cannot interfere with an app unless the target app is designed to permit it (in this case, not), OR, the app is in foreground and script is using some accessibility service UI hack.

Comment: There are dozens of utilities available that will do this for you.  You only have to search for them.

Comment: No, it is not possible to run a batch to change things from inside an app. You couldn't do it on Windows, Linux, Apple devices and you will not be able to do that on Android. You could, however, as Robert said, use the "Do not disturb" to silent your phone during the night automatically.

Comment: settings - apps - whatsapp - notifications - silent

Answer (score -1):

WhatsApp group messages can be muted for 8 hours **or** one week or forever, why not just choose one of those?

Or better yet, just look in the app's notification settings in Android... one of the granular options is [all] "Group chats," and what you set there will take precedence anyway.  "Default" with the notification sound set to None; or set to "Silent," with or without notifications appearing on the lock screen; or best yet, just go with Silent + Minimized = any such notifications are shrunk to a single (but expandable) line + display on the lock screen is disabled automatically.

i.e. still no need to open the full app to check for new messages -- just pull the notification shade down when you care to look, but otherwise they'll stay completely (and permanently) silent & out of sight.

HTH

Comment: Based on the commenters and my understanding, the question wants to have audible WhatsApp notifications on the day but silent notifications on the night automatically. They don't want to silence them permanently.